# How to resize a NumericVector?

Tags: r, rcpp

How can I resize in Rcpp a `NumericVector`?

When I use the `push_back` function for this, the Program slows down. But there are no `.resize()` or `.reserve()` functions.
(When I have already a `NumericVector` with the desired size, I can use the copy-constructor to get the correct size of the `NumericVector`. This is in such a case much faster than usage of `push_back`)

Comment: As Dirk explained, there is very little chance we will have a `reserve` method. We might implement a `resize`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you prefer the C++ idioms, use `std::vector<double>` and return that at the end where it will be converted via an implicit `wrap()` to an R vector.  You could also use Armadillo or Eigen vectors via RcppArmadillo and RcppEigen.

Our objects are shallow wrappers around the R object, so `push_back` on, say, a `Rcp::NumericVector` always needs a full copy. That is known and documented.

*Edit:* So for completeness, here is an example using RcppArmadillo:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec shrink(arma::vec x) {
    arma::vec y = x;
    y.resize( y.size()-2 );
    return y;
}
```

which we can deploy via

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp('/tmp/vec.cpp')
R> shrink(1:10)
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    5
[6,]    6
[7,]    7
[8,]    8
R>
```