# Intersect function with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm having a hard time implementing a function with the `Rcpp` module using `cppFunction`. I need to use something like R's `intersect` with two NumericVector types and return another NumericVector with the result, just like in R.

[This](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-sugar.pdf) document has been of some help but unfortunately I'm pretty much a noob in C++ atm.

How could I implement the `intersect` R function with `cppFunction` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably want to use something like the `unordered_set` to implement `intersect`:

File `myintersect.cpp`:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// Enable C++11 via this plugin (Rcpp 0.10.3 or later)
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector myintersect(NumericVector x, NumericVector y) {
    std::vector<double> res;
    std::unordered_set<double> s(y.begin(), y.end());
    for (int i=0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        auto f = s.find(x[i]);
        if (f != s.end()) {
            res.push_back(x[i]);
            s.erase(f);
        }
    }
    return Rcpp::wrap(res);
}
```

We can load the function and verify it works:

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp(file="myintersect.cpp")

set.seed(144)
x <- c(-1, -1, sample(seq(1000000), 10000, replace=T))
y <- c(-1, sample(seq(1000000), 10000, replace=T))
all.equal(intersect(x, y), myintersect(x, y))
# [1] TRUE
```

However, it seems this approach is a good deal less efficient than the `itersect` function:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(intersect(x, y), myintersect(x, y))
# Unit: microseconds
#               expr      min       lq   median        uq      max neval
#    intersect(x, y)  424.167  495.861  501.919  523.7835  989.997   100
#  myintersect(x, y) 1778.609 1798.111 1808.575 1835.1570 2571.426   100
```

Comment: Nice.  FWIW we also have an ugly uppercase macro giving us `RCPP_UNORDERED_SET` irrespective of the compiler.  But asking via the plugin is more elegant :)

Comment: Ah nice! `std::tr1::unordered_set` wasn't working for me, so it's good to know `RCPP_UNORDERED_SET` exists.

Comment: In addition, there are sugar functions for this, e.g. `intersect` is already available -- but it returns output in a different order than `R`'s `intersect`. (You get the same values, though)

Comment: `push_back` is killing it. Deep copies of all the data every time you use it. Don't `push_back` on Rcpp vectors, ever. FYI, `push_back` ...  have been removed from Rcpp11. @KevinUshey sugar's version does even worse.

Comment: @RomainFrancois thanks -- I followed [Dirk's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782943/how-to-resize-a-numericvector) and converted it to a `std::vector<double>`, but it seems to still be a good deal slower than `intersect`.